# Spinner не имеет заголовка

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Создал `Spinner` присвоил ему адаптер, а после передал адаптеру `View` для пунктов выпадающего списка методом `setDropDownViewResource`. Использовал для этих пунктов стандартный `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`, который должен иметь радиобаттон. Но как видно на скрине, его нет, также как нет и заголовка выпадающего списка, хотя я задал ему текст методом `setPropmt()`.

У меня устаревший урок и теперь слои имеющие заголовок и радиобаттон отличаются?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner spinner;
String[] data = {"one","two","three","four","five"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,data);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setPrompt("ETO ZAGOLOVOK");
    spinner.setSelection(3);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Item " + position + " pressed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner) сказано, что `prompt` используется как заголовок для `Spinner`, если тот работает в режиме диалогового окна.

Добавьте в разметку `Spinner`

```
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
```

и Вы увидите Ваш заголовок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что касается всевозможных "радиобаттонов" и пр., то здесь лучше не пользоваться стандартными адаптерами и шаблонами разметки, а написать свои собственные (примеры можно посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599703/custom-spinner-adapter) и [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/spinner.php)). Это позволит прикрутить практически любой функционал.

Comment: Про заголовок понял, но в чем проблема радиобаттонов? Я нашел в интернете много примеров использования android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, и во всех случаях на скриншоте есть этот радиобаттон. Так почему у меня он работает не так7